# Why are Coldfusion CFM and CFC files not in clear text?

Tags: programming-languages

I am learning Coldfusion, however when I try to open CFM and CFC files they appear to be unreadable.

Some of the data look like java code, but other data looks like this: "¸ aº*3¶ H**´ !½ zY¼S¶".

I thought that this might be compiled with Java, but http://java.decompiler.free.fr does not seem to be able to decompile it.

Comment: It was explained to me that it is so if your web server were to serve up the page in plain text it would not compromise your sensitive code to visitors.  Seeing as it is standard encoding I do not know how much it actually protects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you may have some encrypted files you're looking at.  Most of us CF developers don't really encrypt our code, even though it's possible.  You might be able to decrypt it but it could be a license violation against whoever wrote/licensed the code.  Do a Google search for 'decrypt coldfusion code' and you might find something that will help you.